# How to select non-equal columns from joint tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, mysql-workbench

I have five tables which I need to query them jointly.

The tables are created as follows (for brevity, I will post one create statement, if you need to replicate, repeat the command with changing the name of the table to `t2`, `t3`, `t4`, and `t5`):

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

After creating the tables, I have 2 rows in each table.

`t1` data:

```
# id, name
'1', 'a'
'2', 'b'
```

`t2` data:

```
# id, name
'1', 'a'
'2', 'c'
```

`t3` data:

```
# id, name
'1', 'a'
'2', 'd'
```

`t4` data:

```
# id, name
'1', 'a'
'2', 'e'
```

`t5` data:

```
# id, name
'1', 'a'
'2', 'f'
```

Then I make this query to the 5 tables jointly. The query aims to extract the rows when the `name` is not equal in all of the five tables.

The query:

```
select `t1`.`name` as 't1 name', `t2`.`name` as 't2 name', `t3`.`name` as 't3 name', `t4`.`name` as 't4 name', `t5`.`name` as 't5 name'    
from `test`.`t1`
join `test`.`t2` on `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`id`
join `test`.`t3` on `t2`.`id` = `t3`.`id`
join `test`.`t4` on `t3`.`id` = `t4`.`id`
join `test`.`t5` on `t4`.`id` = `t5`.`id`

where not(`t1`.`name` = `t2`.`name` and 
            `t2`.`name` = `t3`.`name` and 
            `t3`.`name` = `t4`.`name` and 
            `t4`.`name` = `t5`.`name`);
```

My question is:
Is there a better way to form the `where` statement? I just feel it is a long condition. Is there a better way to extract the rows where the name column is not equal in all the tables? Or this is the only possible way to test their equality?

Comment: Five similar tables and supposed to carry same field values, is basically a badly denormalized data. You should rather focus on fixing the table structure and at best, just have one master table storing `id` and `name`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Sameer Can you clarify? The condition aims to extract the rows that do not have name equal in all the 5 tables. So if t1 and t2 have equal name but the rest do not have, the rows will be returned?  Unless all of them equal, they will be returned. If you see somethin wrong, can you plz clarify with example?

Comment: If table 1, table 2 have different data for same id
and table 1, table 3 have same data for same id
do you want that row to be displayed or not.. If that row has to be displayed then it correct

Comment: @Sameer I care about the case when all the five tables have same id BUT not all of them have equal name. These are the cases I want to display. Sorry I did not get your comment so I clarify which cases I want to display. do you still see my method wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you require that the `id` be in all five tables as well as looking for unequal names, then `join` is a reasonable approach.  You can use `least()` and `greatest()` for the comparison:

```
select `t1`.`name` as 't1 name', `t2`.`name` as 't2 name', `t3`.`name` as 't3 name', `t4`.`name` as 't4 name', `t5`.`name` as 't5 name'    
from `test`.`t1` join
     `test`.`t2`
      on `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`id` join
      `test`.`t3`
      on `t2`.`id` = `t3`.`id` join
      `test`.`t4`
      on `t3`.`id` = `t4`.`id` join
      `test`.`t5`
      on `t4`.`id` = `t5`.`id`
where least(t1.name, t2.name, t3.name, t4.name, t5.name) <> greatest(t1.name, t2.name, t3.name, t4.name, t5.name);
```

If you want to find `id`s that are not in all five table or have different names, then the above will not work.  For this, use `union all` with a slight variation on Salman's approach:

```
select id, group_concat(distinct name) as names
from ((select id, name, 1 as which from t1) union all
      (select id, name, 2 as which from t2) union all
      (select id, name, 3 as which from t3) union all
      (select id, name, 4 as which from t4) union all
      (select id, name, 5 as which from t5)   
     ) t
group by id
having count(distinct which) <> 5 or
       min(name) <> max(name);
```

Comment: @seq . . . It should work *assuming you insist that ids be in all five tables*.

Comment: There is one of the comment (by @Sameer) saying it is wrong.

Comment: Yes. Ids in all tables. I can not change the structure. It is for analysis and it has been gathered in this way and should be stored separately.

Comment: Sorry about confusion. I just need ids that appear in all the five tables that's why I use join. I care about those that appear in all the five tables. I just wanted to ask if there is anything wrong in my original post? I want to improve and your first part make sense to me. But is my post correct just in case if I want to keep my way. Because @Sameer comment says it is wrong.

Comment: thanks. But I already use `and` and `not`. Do you see anything wrong in my query?

Comment: @seq . . . I think I scrolled up to an earlier answer rather than the question.  Your code with the `and` looks correct.